# Deleting junction objects

Tags: apex, master-detail, junction-object

I have a use case where the Master object can only have one child object at a time, so when a user selects a new child object I need to delete the original junction object via Apex and create a new one for the new child object.  I have full CRED access to the junction object but can't seem to delete it.  The debug log shows that I am getting to and performing the DML delete statement but when I query for the object immediately after deleting it it is still being found, any suggestions? (The delete statement is the top part of the function and the entirety of the class is below that) [image]

```
if(originalSalesRep.Id != salesRep){
        Id osrId = originalSalesRep.Id;
        Survey_Worker__c junctionToDelete = [SELECT Id, Survey_WorkerId__c FROM Survey_Worker__c WHERE Survey_Worker__c.Survey_WorkerId__c = :osrId LIMIT 1];
        delete junctionToDelete;
    }


@AuraEnabled
public static Survey__c savePIS(Id recordId, String firstName, String lastName, String email, 
                                String phone, String shippingDate, 
                                Id techMeasurer, Id salesRep, List<Id> installers, Worker__c originalSalesRep 
                                ){
    Date stringToDate = null;
    List<Survey_Worker__c> junctionList = new List<Survey_Worker__c>();
    List<Survey_Worker__c> removeJunctionList = new List<Survey_Worker__c>();
    system.debug('shippingDate: ' + shippingDate);
    if(!shippingDate.equals('') && !shippingDate.equals(null)){
        stringToDate = Date.valueOf(shippingDate);
    } 
    Survey__c survey = [SELECT Id, Primary_Contact_First_Name__c,
        Primary_Contact_Last_Name__c,
        Primary_Contact_Email__c,
        Primary_Contact_Mobile_Phone__c,
        Shipping_Date__c FROM Survey__c WHERE Id = :recordId LIMIT 1];

    survey.Primary_Contact_First_Name__c = firstName;
    survey.Primary_Contact_Last_Name__c = lastName;
    survey.Primary_Contact_Email__c = email;
    survey.Primary_Contact_Mobile_Phone__c = phone;

    survey.Shipping_Date__c = stringToDate;
    Database.upsert(survey, true);
    system.debug('shippingDateSurvey: ' + survey.Shipping_Date__c);

    if(installers.size() > 0){
        for(Id w : installers){
        Survey_Worker__c installerJunc = new Survey_Worker__c(
            Survey_LogId__c = survey.Id,
            Survey_WorkerId__c = w,
            Role__c = 'Installer'
        );
        junctionList.add(installerJunc);
        }
    }
    system.debug('originalSalesRep: ' + originalSalesRep.Id);
    system.debug('salesRepId: ' + salesRep);
    if(originalSalesRep.Id != salesRep){
        Id osrId = originalSalesRep.Id;
        Survey_Worker__c junctionToDelete = [SELECT Id, Survey_WorkerId__c FROM Survey_Worker__c WHERE Survey_Worker__c.Survey_WorkerId__c = :osrId LIMIT 1];
        delete junctionToDelete;
        //removeJunctionList.add(junctionToDelete);
    }
    system.debug('removeList: '+removeJunctionList);
    if(salesRep != null){
        Survey_Worker__c salesRepJunction = new Survey_Worker__c(
        Survey_LogId__c = survey.Id,
        Survey_WorkerId__c = salesRep,
        Role__c = 'Sales Rep'
        );
        junctionList.add(salesRepJunction); 
    }

    if(techMeasurer != null){
        Survey_Worker__c techMeasuerJunction = new Survey_Worker__c(
        Survey_LogId__c = survey.Id,
        Survey_WorkerId__c = techMeasurer,
        Role__c = 'Tech Measurer'
        );
        junctionList.add(techMeasuerJunction);
    }

    if(junctionList.size() > 0){
        Database.upsert(junctionList, true);
    }
    if(removeJunctionList.size() > 0){
        Database.delete(removeJunctionList, true);
    }
    return survey;

}
```

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: I added the entire classs @kurunve

Comment: what do you mean "query immediately after deleting"? are you sure that you are not getting another "sales rep" worker record? can you post your query as well?

Comment: Thanks for helping hurunve I just figured it out, I was limiting my query to just one junction object.  I was specifying which child object but wasn't specifying which parent object in my query and as a result it was just deleting the first junction object associated with that child instead of deleting the one I was watching